# Not able to render Adaptive card in MS Teams using Bot Framework SDK v4

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

I am trying to render Adaptive card in MS Teams and getting Message "The specified card version is not supported."
I am using Bot Framework SDK v4 - node.js

Below is code Snippets: **below Adaptive card in welcome.json**

```
{
"contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
"content": {
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.0",
    "body": [
        {
           "type": "TextBlock",
           "text": "Default text input"
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
           "type": "Action.Submit",
           "title": "OK"
        }
    ]
   }  
}
```

**Node.js Code:**

```
const { ActivityTypes, CardFactory } = require('botbuilder');
const WelcomeDialogCard = require('./Welcome.json');
let strJson = JSON.stringify(WelcomeDialogCard );
const cardJson = JSON.parse(strJson);
const confirmationCard = CardFactory.adaptiveCard(cardJson);
await turnContext.sendActivity({ attachments: [confirmationCard ] });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your adaptive card wasn't formatted correctly. The type, version, body, and action attributes should all be in the top level of the JSON object. Take a look at the example below.

#### AdaptiveCard

```
{
    "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.0",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Default"
        }
    ],
    "actions": [{
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "OK"
    }]
}
```

#### Node

```
const WelcomeDialogCard = require('./Welcome.json');

const confirmationCard = CardFactory.adaptiveCard(WelcomeDialogCard)
await turnContext.sendActivity({ attachments: [confirmationCard] });
```

I would highly recommend using the [AdaptiveCard Designer](https://adaptivecards.io/designer/) to help create your cards, and note you shouldn't have to stringify and parse the AdaptiveCard.

Hope this helps!